# Signalr (1.0.0-alpha2) Hubs - Can you add client functions after connection has been started?

Tags: signalr, signalr-hub

Using Signalr (1.0.0-alpha2), I want to know if it is possible to add client functions after a connection has been started.

Say I create my connection and grab the proxy.  Then I add some Server Fired client functions to the hub to do a few things.  Then I start my connection.  I then want to add some more Server Fired functions to my hub object.  Is this possible?

```
var myHub= $.connection.myHub;
myHub.SomeClientFunction = function() {
   alert("serverside called 'Clients.SomeClientFunction()'");
};
$.connection.hub.start()
   .done(function() {
      myHub.SomeNewClientFunction = function() {
        alert("serverside called 'Clients.SomeNewClientFunction()'");
      }
    })
```

This example is not realistic, but I basically want to send my 'myHub' variable to a different object after the hub is started to subscribe to new events that the original code did not care for.

Real Life Example:  A dashboard with a number of different hub events (new site visits, chat message, site error).  I 'subscribe' after the connection has started and then pass my hub proxy to all of my different UI components to handle their specific 'message types'.  Should I create separate Hubs for these or should I be able to add more Server Fired client functions on the fly?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Yes you can.  Use the .on method.

Example:

```
myHub.on('somethingNew', function() {
    alert("This was called after the connection started!");
});
```

If you want to remove it later on use the .off method.

Comment: You need to have at least one subscription before calling start.

Comment: @dfowler is that one subscription per hub or in total? Also does subscription just mean already having a function for the server to call?

Comment: Per hub. Subscription means you have a callback defined on the client side.

Answer (score 0):

I have the exact same situation. You might want to consider adding another layout of abstraction if you're trying to call it from multiple places.

Here's a preliminary version of what I've come up with (typescript).

I'll start with the usage. `SignalRManager` is my 'manager' class that abstracts my `debuggingHub` hub. I have a client method `fooChanged` that is triggered on the server.

Somewhere in the module that is using SignalR I just call the `start` method, which is not re-started if already started.

```
// ensure signalR is started
SignalRManager.start().done(() =>
{
    $.connection.debuggingHub.server.init();
});
```

Your 'module' simply registers its callback through the manager class and whenever the SignalR client method is triggered your handler is called.

```
// handler for foo changed
SignalRManager.onFooChanged((guid: string) =>
{
    if (this.currentSession().guid == guid)
    {
        alert('changed');
    }
});
```

This is a simple version of `SignalRManager` that uses jQuery `$.Callbacks` to pass on the request to as many modules as you have. Of course you could use any mechanism you wanted, but this seems to be the simplest.

```
module RR 
{ 
    export class SignalRManager
    {
        // the original promise returned when calling hub.Start
        static _start: JQueryPromise<any>;

        private static _fooChangedCallback = $.Callbacks();

        // add callback for 'fooChanged' callback
        static onfooChanged(callback: (guid: string) => any)
        {
            SignalRManager._fooChangedCallback.add(callback);
        }

        static start(): JQueryPromise<any>
        {
            if (!SignalRManager._start)
            {
                // callback for fooChanged
                $.connection.debuggingHub.client.fooChanged = (guid: string) =>
                {
                    console.log('foo Changed ' + guid);
                    SignalRManager._fooChangedCallback.fire.apply(arguments);                    
                };

                // start hub and save the promise returned
                SignalRManager._start = $.connection.hub.start().done(() =>
                {
                    console.log('Signal R initialized');
                });
            }

            return SignalRManager._start;
        }
    }
}
```

Note: there may be extra work involved to handle disconnections or connections lost.