# Replacing SignalR callbacks doesn't work

Tags: signalr

**UPDATE**: I simplified the error case further and filed an issue on SignalR's GitHub page. You can see the issue here: https://github.com/SignalR/SignalR/issues/1828. Actually this bug has nothing to do with AngularJS.

I have a project which uses ASP.NET and SignalR on the backend and AngularJS as a frontend. Everything works fine except when I move within the AngularJS and controllers get created again, they cannot replace the original SignalR callback methods.

Here is the code for my controller:

```
function SignalRProblemCtrl($scope) {
    var bar = $.connection.bar;
    $.connection.hub.start();

    $scope.currentMessage = "";

    $scope.messages = [];
    $scope.messages.push("HELLO!");

    var date = new Date();
    bar.client.addMessage = function (message) {
        $scope.$apply(function () {
            console.log("Callback set on " + date + ": " + message);
            $scope.messages.push(message);
        });
    };

    $scope.send = function () {
        bar.server.send($scope.currentMessage, "Extra data");
    };

}
SignalRProblemCtrl.$inject = ['$scope'];
```

On my first visit to this controller I can send and receive messages and all my Angular bindings work fine. My console has output:

```
Callback set on Fri Apr 05 2013 14:37:13 GMT+0300 (E. Europe Daylight Time): First page load controllers.js:37
```

This is all good and dandy. The problem arises after moving to another page and vising SignalRProblemCtrl again. This time I can send and receive messages, message gets written to console BUT my bindings will not be updated. The output in the console points to the root cause:

```
Callback set on Fri Apr 05 2013 14:37:13 GMT+0300 (E. Europe Daylight Time): Second page load controllers.js:37
```

So my bindings don't get updated because on second creation of controller the first callback doesn't get replaced. All SignalR messages still go to the first callback which has the $scope of the previous instance of the controller and thus my view doesn't get updated with the latest messages.

Why is this? Why does the SignalR hold on to the first callback?

PS. I also tried replacing the callback immediately. With this code the latest callback (one with date2) is used correctly.

```
var date = new Date();
bar.client.addMessage = function (message) {
    $scope.$apply(function () {
        console.log("Callback set on " + date + ": " + message);
        $scope.messages.push(message);
    });
};

var date2 = new Date();
bar.client.addMessage = function (message) {
    $scope.$apply(function () {
        console.log("Callback set on " + date2 + ": " + message);
        $scope.messages.push(message);
    });
};
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Signalr (1.0.0-alpha2) Hubs - Can you add client functions after connection has been started?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13497390/signalr-1-0-0-alpha2-hubs-can-you-add-client-functions-after-connection-has)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After filing an issue on Github (https://github.com/SignalR/SignalR/issues/1828) I got a comment about how to solve this.

You can check out the solution at: [Signalr (1.0.0-alpha2) Hubs - Can you add client functions after connection has been started?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13497390/signalr-1-0-0-alpha2-hubs-can-you-add-client-functions-after-connection-has)